# Substring after last character in xslt

Tags: xslt

I can't find the exact answer for this question so I hope someone will help me here.

I have a string and I want get the substring after the last '.'. I'm using xslt 1.0.

How is this done? This is my code.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:otherwise> 
        <xsl:attribute name="class">method txt-align-left case-names</xsl:attribute>&#160;
        <xsl:value-of select="./@name"/> // this prints a string eg: 'something1.something2.something3'
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

When i paste the suggested code I get an error message. "Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do this with a single expression in XSLT 1.0, but you can do it with a recursive template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <n>
      <xsl:call-template name="GetLastSegment">
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="'something1.something2.something3'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="'.'" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </n>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="GetLastSegment">
    <xsl:param name="value" />
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="'.'" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($value, $separator)">
        <xsl:call-template name="GetLastSegment">
          <xsl:with-param name="value" select="substring-after($value, $separator)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<n>something3</n>
```

Comment: You would do this: `<xsl:call-template name="GetLastSegment"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="@name" /><xsl:with-param name="separator" value="'.'" /></xsl:call-template>`  If you can't get that to work, could you edit your question to include all the relevant portions of your XSLT?

Comment: how can I get a value on possition? like something2?

Answer (score 3):

I did the same behaviour with a xsl:function - usage is then a little bit simpler:

```
<xsl:function name="ns:substring-after-last" as="xs:string" xmlns:ns="yourNamespace">
    <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:string?"/>
    <xsl:param name="separator" as="xs:string"/>        
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($value, $separator)">
            <xsl:value-of select="ns:substring-after-last(substring-after($value, $separator), $separator)" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

And you can call it directly in a value-of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ns:substring-after-last(.,'=')" xmlns:ns="yourNamespace"/>
```

Comment: Where is namespace dp coming from ? `dp:substring-after-last(substring-after($value, $separator), $separator)"`

Comment: Thanks Hayra. There was indeed a copy/paste error in the namespace prefix. I just updated the code.

Comment: which namespace is ns?

Comment: ns is your namespace. See first line containing the declaration with xmln:ns="yourcompany.com"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using [EXSLT str:tokenize](http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/):

```
<xsl:if test="substring($string, string-length($string)) != '.'"><xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize($string, '.')[last()]" /></xsl:if>
```

(the `if` is here because if your string ends with the separator, tokenize won't return an empty string)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it

```
<xsl:call-template name="GetLastSegment">
<xsl:with-param name="value" select="./@name" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Did not need the

```
<xsl:with-param name="separator" value="'.'" />
```

in the template call