# How to remove some content from the elements using XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt

For the image tag, I need to keep only the image file with "file/" content using XSLT in the JSON output:

My input XML file is:

```
<image>binary/alias/my.jpg</image>
```

XSL which is used as:

```
<xsl:template match="image">
  image: <xsl:apply-templates/>,
</xsl:template>
```

JSON output which I get is:

```
image: binary/alias/my.jpg
```

I need the output as:

```
image: files/my.jpg
```

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which XSLT processor will you be using?

Comment: version="2.0" @Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 you can do:

```
<xsl:template match="image">
    <xsl:text>image: files/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., '/')[last()]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the string after the last occurrence of a char (in this case '/') you need (in XSLT-1.0) a recursive template. Applying this template, the solution is straightforward: Output the desired prefix text 'image: files/' and append the result of the recursive template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="image">
    image: files/<xsl:call-template name="LastOccurrence">
      <xsl:with-param name="value" select="text()" />
      <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="'/'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template name="LastOccurrence">
    <xsl:param name="value" />
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="'/'" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($value, $separator)">
        <xsl:call-template name="LastOccurrence">
          <xsl:with-param name="value" select="substring-after($value, $separator)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `LastOccurrence` template was inspired by [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17469170/1305969).

Comment: This also working fine @ZX485. I followed the below one. Thanks for your code.